# How to ssh into freenom domain

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

I have created a free domain with *freenom.com* and I am trying to connect to it via `ssh user@example.ml` in a Ubuntu 22.04 VDI. The objective is, once I connect, to launch `docker-compose --build`. The problem is, the ssh command fails with error: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname example.ml: No address associated with hostname".

**What originated the problem?**

This question is related to the testdriven.io series of articles on how to build and deploy your Django application. In detail, my question is relatad to the second article of the three. Everything works fine as we build locally the application with nginx and gunicorn. Then, he uses a linux command `ssh user@your-ip-or-domain` to connect to the host, which I think might be the name of the domain he suggests to create with *freenom.com*.

Now, I am on a Windows machine and have no idea how to perform this operation that he does not explain (should we copy the project on a virtualbox with linux? should you run an image of linux with docker?).

The article I am referring is [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-lets-encrypt/) in the **"Running the Containers"** paragraph. I am looking for a deeper explanation of that phase.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://medium.com/@federicodeicas/how-to-setup-your-server-with-freenom-tk-82c7302bcce4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A domain doesn't automatically have a system that you could SSH to. What you have is just the phonebook entry alone – you still have to get the actual server from somewhere else (and then use Freenom's control panel to point your domain to that server's IP address).

(There are many web hosting companies that sell you a Linux virtual server *and* a preconfigured domain name as a package, but Freenom is only a domain registrar and doesn't deal in server hosting.)

So your next step would be to choose a server hosting company and pay them for a small Linux virtual machine. At first you will SSH to it by IP address (at least to test/look around), but you can use Freenom's control panel to assign the address to your domain name.

(You probably *could* do most things on your PC with Linux inside VirtualBox, if you spend additional time setting up "port forwarding" to make the VM publicly accessible – but hosted servers already have a dedicated IP address included in the purchase so it's much easier.)

> Now, I am on a Windows machine and have no idea how to perform this operation that he does not explain (should we copy the project on a virtualbox with linux? should you run an image of linux with docker?).

It doesn't matter – this operation doesn't do anything to your project, it only lets you connect to the server in general.

The `ssh` command exists in Windows 10, and there are other SSH clients (such as PuTTY or Bitvise) available for Windows. There are also Windows SFTP apps (such as WinSCP or the `sftp` command) for transferring files to the server.

As far as I can understand the tutorial, it assumes that you *already have* your project fully set up for running in Docker, i.e. instead of the demonstration "django-on-docker" Git repository you're supposed to `git clone` your own repo (with the project + the Dockerfiles + everything) that you probably made [according to the previous tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/).

It's not a very good tutorial.

Comment: I can see that there are plenty of concepts and steps to follow. I have added the guide I was following for securitizing a Django application with SSL. The author just did it in one step but it seems like he skips a lot!

Comment: @ilovebees: The author did include "...a running Linux virtual machine with Docker and Docker Compose installed" as part of the article's 'Prerequisites'. (Well, not necessarily a virtual machine, a physical server would also work, but most people use a VM.) They skipped the process of configuring the domain name, probably because it's not the focus of the article (and slightly varies depending on which registrar you got the domain from).

Comment: To start I want to thank you for the help you are providing. So, I got to the step where I have the domain of freenom.com and I set up the custom nameservers through Cloudflare. Now, from what I understand the next step would be to set the DNS of example.ml via Cloudflare. Assuming I'm using an Ubuntu 22.04 image on Virtualbox, do I have to provide the IP of the VDI? (Also, yes, loacally in my Windows 11 I have a fully working Docker Django project with Celery, Postgresql, Nginx, Gunicorn).

Comment: For A/AAAA records, it's the IP address of whatever system you want the domain to point to. (In most cases it's the public IP address of some server or router; using a local/private IP address will make the domain only accessible locally as well.)